# Implementation of the Heap Sort algorithm in C++

Tags: c++, sorting, c++14, heap, heap-sort

I'm writing a little collection of sorting algorithms and some benchmarks (using Google benchmark). 
I wrote the following `heap sort` but I'm struggling in understanding why it is so slower than [std::sort_heap](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort_heap) implemented in the <del>`STL`</del> *C++ Stardard Library*. The code is inspired to the algorithm described in Cormen book "Introduction to algorithms"

Am I doing something silly?
I have also profiled the code using `perf` and it seems that the hottest instruction is the comparison function.

Here it goes my implementation:

```
template <typename Iterator>
inline Iterator left_child(const Iterator begin, Iterator idx) {
  return idx + std::distance(begin, idx) + 1;  
}

template <class Iterator>
inline Iterator right_child(const Iterator begin, Iterator idx) {
  return left_child(begin, idx) + 1;
}

template <class Iterator>
inline Iterator parent(Iterator begin, Iterator idx) {
  return begin + std::distance(begin + 1, idx) / 2;
}

template <typename Iterator, typename CMP_FN>
inline void heapify(const Iterator begin, const Iterator end, Iterator idx,
                       CMP_FN cmp) {
  bool go = true;
  while (go) {
    const Iterator left(left_child(begin, idx));
    const Iterator right(right_child(begin, idx));
    Iterator candidate(idx);
    // this if relies on if short circuiting cmp has to be guarded for segfault
    if (left < end && !cmp(*left, *idx)) candidate = left;
    //this if relies on if short circuiting cmp has to be guarded for segfault
    if (right < end && !cmp(*right, *candidate)) candidate = right;

    if (candidate != idx) {
      std::swap(*candidate, *idx);
      // go=true;
      idx = candidate;
    } else
      go = false;
  }
}

template <typename Iterator, typename CMP_FN>
inline void build_heap(const Iterator begin, const Iterator end, CMP_FN cmp) {
  const auto d = distance(begin, end) / 2;
  for (Iterator s = begin + d; s >= begin; s--)
    heapify(begin, end, s, cmp);

}

/////////////////////////////////////////////////
/// @Brief Heap sort implementation (inspiration from Cormen et al Book)
// CMP_FN has type: D -> D -> bool
/////////////////////////////////////////////////
template <typename Iterator, typename CMP_FN>
void heap_sort(Iterator s, Iterator e, CMP_FN cmp) {
  auto d = std::distance(s,e);
  if(d <= 1)
    return;

  build_heap(s, e, cmp);
  while(d--){
    e--;
    std::swap(*s, *e);
    heapify(s, e, s, cmp);
  }
}
```

When benchmarked those are the timings I get:

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Benchmark                                                          Time           CPU Iterations
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
benchmark_random_values<quicksorter_hoare>/32768             2 ms          2 ms        154
benchmark_random_values<quicksorter_hoare>/65536             4 ms          4 ms         73
benchmark_random_values<quicksorter_hoare>/131072            8 ms          8 ms         34
benchmark_random_values<quicksorter_hoare>/262144           17 ms         17 ms         16
benchmark_random_values<quicksorter_hoare>/524288           36 ms         36 ms          8
benchmark_random_values<quicksorter_hoare>/1048576          77 ms         77 ms          4
benchmark_random_values<quicksorter_hoare>/2097152         159 ms        159 ms          2
benchmark_random_values<quicksorter_hoare>/4194304         336 ms        336 ms          1
benchmark_random_values<quicksorter_hoare>/8388608         701 ms        701 ms          1
benchmark_random_values<quicksorter_hoare>/16777216       1466 ms       1466 ms          1
benchmark_random_values<heap_sorter>/32768                   2 ms          2 ms        111
benchmark_random_values<heap_sorter>/65536                   5 ms          5 ms         53
benchmark_random_values<heap_sorter>/131072                 12 ms         12 ms         24
benchmark_random_values<heap_sorter>/262144                 25 ms         25 ms         11
benchmark_random_values<heap_sorter>/524288                 55 ms         55 ms          5
benchmark_random_values<heap_sorter>/1048576               120 ms        120 ms          2
benchmark_random_values<heap_sorter>/2097152               264 ms        264 ms          1
benchmark_random_values<heap_sorter>/4194304               659 ms        659 ms          1
benchmark_random_values<heap_sorter>/8388608              1657 ms       1657 ms          1
benchmark_random_values<heap_sorter>/16777216             4038 ms       4038 ms          1
benchmark_random_values<sort_heap_std>/32768                 2 ms          2 ms        108
benchmark_random_values<sort_heap_std>/65536                 5 ms          5 ms         60
benchmark_random_values<sort_heap_std>/131072                9 ms          9 ms         30
benchmark_random_values<sort_heap_std>/262144               20 ms         20 ms         12
benchmark_random_values<sort_heap_std>/524288               40 ms         40 ms          7
benchmark_random_values<sort_heap_std>/1048576              87 ms         87 ms          3
benchmark_random_values<sort_heap_std>/2097152             175 ms        175 ms          2
benchmark_random_values<sort_heap_std>/4194304             365 ms        365 ms          1
benchmark_random_values<sort_heap_std>/8388608             757 ms        757 ms          1
benchmark_random_values<sort_heap_std>/16777216           1736 ms       1736 ms          1
```

As you can see from the timing the heap sorter is much slower than the `std::sort_heap` and also than a quicksort that I wrote.

Comment: As an aside, do you know [What's the difference between “STL” and “C++ Standard Library”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5205491/whats-the-difference-between-stl-and-c-standard-library)

Comment: Apparently, I did not! XD

Comment: @Deduplicator Thanks for this link. Is it okay to simply say `stdlib` when refering to the standard library?

Comment: @yuri Yes, standard library is quite a mouthful ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Well, before we even consider efficiency, lets look at correctness.
Your code invokes [Undefined Behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397984/undefined-unspecified-and-implementation-defined-behavior):

Specifically, you create iterators which will refer far past the range you got in `left_child()` and `right_child()` after you swapped a leaf-node in heapify.

That probably also answers for your programs speed.

Or maybe you compared `heap_sort()` performance with `std::sort_heap()`, which is completely unfair as the former corresponds to the combination of `std::make_heap()`+`std::sort_heap()`.

---

Why do you split `heapsort()` into two words like `heap_sort()`? That at best confuses.

You would normally call the function which builds the whole heap `heapify()`, though `build_heap()` isn't that uncommon. I would keep to `make_heap()` like the standard uses though.

The helper-function you unaccountably called `heapify()` even though it's just a small step in building a heap would normally be called `sift_down()`, `down_heap()` or a variant thereof.

I would expect a (preprocessor-) constant under `CMP_FN` instead of a template parameter. Why don't you use the more common `Compare`, `Comp` or `Cmp`, especially as it need not be a function, only a callable?

A qualified call to `std::swap(a, b)` cannot pick up specializations in other namespaces using ADL. Use `using std::swap; swap(a, b);` or `std::iter_swap(pa, pb);`.

Regarding "something silly": Avoid using flags for flow-control, dedicated control-structures are easier to follow.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I fixed the `left_child`  functions by checking `if (distance(idx, end-2) < distance(begin, idx)` and if that fails returning `end`(the right_child similarly). Is that what you were refereeing to as UB?  Regarding the performance, the problem is still there.  What do you mean that the comparison is unfair? shouldn't make_heap correspond to my `build_heap` and sort_heap to my `heap_sort`? Plus thanks for the stylistic comments. I fill fix them up right away.

Comment: Read it: [`std::sort_heap`: *Converts the max heap [first, last) into a sorted range in ascending order.*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort_heap)

Comment: Obviously I am benchmarking `make_heap`+`sort_heap` vs my `heap_sort`